# Avoid recursion in zsh command line

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

OK, I switched to zsh a few hours ago and I am in a huge config-fooling around spree, but this is likely a too big bite for me:

I'd like to to do a delimiter autopairnig, e.g. type ( and it inserts (). First fail:

`bindkey -s "(" "()"`

Second fail:

```
function autopair () {
zle -U "()"
zle backward-char
}
zle -N autopair autopair
bindkey "(" autopair
```

I think both fail because zsh tries to recurse on the "(" insert (`-U` seems to say this explicitly). Is there a way to avoid this? Substituting `echo -ne "()"` in the 1st line of the function of course avoids this but is uneditable... Any ideas how to force insert?

Bonus points (figuratively speaking:)): I'd like to set the cursor between the brackets after insertion. The `zle backward-char` in my function however doesn't do anything...

Just imagine how awesome this could be! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function autopair()
{
    LBUFFER+="("
    RBUFFER=")$RBUFFER"
}
zle -N autopair autopair
bindkey "(" autopair
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work for me... No errors, just does not insert anything after "(". I've only copied your snippet to my .zshrc (and sourced it) - or do I have to also somehow call it?

Comment: @user673592 *Try replacing your function*. I have not written all this zle stuff because it already was in your question.

Comment: Updated so that solution is obvious (copied that two lines from your question).

Comment: My gosh I can be such an idiot! (To my defense I was in a terrible rush earlier today...). Yes, this works and is awesome beyond measure! Thanks so much!